# How to programmatically switch NavigationViewControllers in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

In my Main.storyboard, I have 2 NavigationControllers, SplashNavigationController and LoggedInNavigationController.

How can I programmatically go from a ViewControler in SplashNavigationController to the root of LoggedInNavigationController?(I've created a button in the LoginViewController[in the SplashNavigationController] that can segue to it, but I was wondering how i can do it programmatically from my ViewController that controls new accounts)

[image: CreateAccountViewController needing to programmatically display LoggedInNavigationController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to instantiate your `LoggedInNavigationController` from storyboard and present it like this:

```
var loggedInNavController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("LoggedInNavControllerStoryboardId");
PresentViewController(loggedInNavController, true, null);
```

Just make sure you set Storyboard Id for `LoggedInNavigationController` in storyboard.